# Need Help porting project to latest vtk version from 5.8 version

Tags: c++, vtk

I am working on a project which includes following code. This code was developed in vtk5.8 and now I am trying to make it work in vtk9.1. The code is compiling but it is not rendering anything. Can Anyone look at the code and let me know any specific reason.

```
this->ren = vtkRenderer::New();
this->renWin = vtkWin32OpenGLRenderWindow::New();

this->iren = vtkWin32RenderWindowInteractor::New();
this->Actor = vtkActor::New();
this->ren->AddActor(this->Actor);
this->renWin->AddRenderer(this->ren);
this->iren->SetRenderWindow(this->renWin);

vtkPolyData* data = vtkPolyData::New();
vtkCellArray *polys = vtkCellArray::New();
vtkPoints *newPts = vtkPoints::New();

Internal code to fill newpts and polys with data is working fine*

data->SetPoints(newPts);
data->SetPolys(polys);
pMapper->SetInputData(data);
this->Actor->SetMapper(mapper);
this->ren->SetBackground(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
this->ren->SetAmbient(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
this->ren->RemoveAllViewProps();
this->renWin->Render();
```

Comment: This is a far cry from a [mre]. There could be all kinds of reasons for not rendering something.

Answer (score 0):

Add this->iren->Start(); after this->renWin->Render();

Without this->iren->Start(); Event loop won't be started.